# Boyd & Vandenberghe, page 488 — convergence analysis of Newton's method

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson

On page 487 of Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook), the convergenge analysis of Newton's method (Algorithm 9.5) is based on the **backtracking line search**. My questions are around (9.33) on Page 488. The assumption is $\eta \leq m^2/L$ where $m$ is the constant of strongly convexity, and $L$ is the Lipschitz constant for the Hessian of $f$, i.e., $\nabla^2f(x)$.

1. In the paragraph under (9.33), it says that if $\left\|\nabla f\left(x^{(k)}\right)\right\|_{2}<\eta$, then $\left\|\nabla f\left(x^{(k+1)}\right)\right\|_{2}<\eta$ because of **$\eta\leq m^2/L$**. Why is this? How can we get this result for the iteration $k+1$? That is to say, **$\left\|\nabla f\left(x^{(l)}\right)\right\|_{2}<\eta$ holds for all $l\geq k$**.
2. Also, in the end of that paragraph, it says that '' Therefore for all $l\geq k$, the algorithm takes a full Newton step $t=1$''. Why is **$t^{(k)}=1$ once $\left\|\nabla f\left(x^{(k)}\right)\right\|_{2}<\eta$**, not a number less than $1$?

Comment: [Listed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33414/339790)

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, let $g(t)=\|\nabla f(x+t\Delta x_{nt})\|_2^2$ with $t\ge 0$, then since $\Delta x_{nt}=-\nabla^2f(x)^{-1}\nabla f(x)$ we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
g'(t) &= 2\nabla f(x+t\Delta x_{nt})^T \nabla^2 f(x+t\Delta x_{nt})\Delta x_{nt}
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
g'(0) &= 2\nabla f(x)^T\nabla^2 f(x)\Delta x_{nt}\\
&=2\nabla f(x)^T\nabla^2 f(x)(-\nabla^2f(x)^{-1}\nabla f(x))\\
&=-2\nabla f(x)^T\nabla f(x)\\
&<0
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $g'(t)$ is continuous, there exists $t>0$ such that $g(t)<g(0)$, i.e., $\|\nabla f(x^{(k)}+t\Delta x^{(k)}_{nt})\|_2^2=\|\nabla f(x^{(k+1)})\|_2^2<\|\nabla f(x^{(k)})\|_2^2$. But this has nothing to do with $\eta\le m^2/L$(we didn't use this condition in the above derivation) and only answers the first question, why is $t=1$ for all $l\geq k$?

Answer (score 0):

The idea *very briefly*: Newton's method is (with obvious notations $\nabla f_k=\nabla f(x_k)$ etc)
$$
(x_{k+1}-x_k=)\quad\Delta x_k=-\nabla^2f_k^{-1}\nabla f_k\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad \nabla f_k+\nabla^2f_k\Delta x_k=0.
$$

1. Taylor: $\nabla f_{k+1}=\nabla f_k+\nabla^2f(\xi)\Delta x_k$.
2. Estimate (use 1. + triangle inequality + Lipschitz)
   $$
   \nabla f_{k+1}=\nabla f_{k+1}-0=\nabla f_{k+1}-(\nabla f_k+\nabla^2f_k\Delta x_k)=
   (\nabla^2f(\xi)-\nabla^2f_k)\Delta x_k.
   $$
3. Estimate (triangle inequality + $\nabla^2 f\ge m I$)
   $$
   \Delta x_k=-\nabla^2f_k^{-1}\nabla f_k.
   $$
   The result will read
   $$
   \|\nabla f_{k+1}\|\le\frac{L}{m^2}\eta^2.
   $$
   The rest should be obvious by now.

---

For the extra $1/2$: use the [integral form of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder)

1. Taylor: $\nabla f_{k+1}=\nabla f_k+\int_0^1\nabla^2f(x_k+t\Delta x_k)\Delta x_k\,dt$
2. Estimate:
   \begin{align}
   \|\nabla f_{k+1}\|&=\|\nabla f_{k+1}-(\nabla f_k+\nabla^2f_k\Delta x_k)\|\\
   &=\left\|\int_0^1(\nabla^2f(x_k+t\Delta x_k)-\nabla^2f_k)\Delta x_k\,dt\right\|\\
   &\le\int_0^1\|\nabla^2f(x_k+t\Delta x_k)-\nabla^2f(x_k)\|\cdot\|\Delta x_k\|\,dt.\\
   &\le L\int_0^1 t\|\Delta x_k\|^2 dt\\
   &= \frac{L}{2}\|\Delta x_k\|^2\\
   &=\frac{L}{2}\|\nabla^2f_k^{-1}\nabla f_k\|^2\\
   &\le \frac{L}{2m^2}\|\nabla f_k\|^2
   \end{align}

Comment: Your derivation is weaker. There is a 1/2, i.e. $\frac{L}{m^2}$, in (9.33) on Page 488. Your answer is helpful.

Comment: @suineg Just to prevent misunderstanding: it is the proof of the statement 1 in your question, there is no $1/2$ in it. I am not proving (9.33).

Comment: @suineg if you need extra $1/2$ you should take the integral form of the remainder. I will update the question.

Comment: The integral form has been shown on Page 491 in B & V's book.

Comment: @suineg Good. I see that you have got it.